# Objective C: make a POST request using SHA512

Tags: objective-c, post, sha512

I need to acces an API on https://btc-e.com/api/documentation. I've been googling and trying lots of stuff for 3 days right now and I completely lost any hope that I can access that API.

It needs POST request to be encrypted with SHA512 and signed with secret key.

So, I try to implement it in Objective C.

Function where I have issues

```
NSString *hmacForKeyAndData(NSString *key, NSString *data)
{
const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA512, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *enryptedData= [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
// encryptedData seems to be in right form
// <ef56b041 12345678 12345678 12345678 a6128b61 12345678 f409507e 12345678 54a91f40 52f491e0 12345678 18942391 12345678 b2749b14 12345678 12345678>
NSString *result;

// HERE: I need to somehow convert NSData to NSString

return result;
}
```

I just cannot get how to encrypt this message right and how to convert it to string that I can then send as POST parameter :(

Can you please help me how to deal with SHA512 with key signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API failed to mention that they want the signature to be base64 encoded. This site gives a pretty good example of how to do so http://agerson.net/base64-encode-and-decode-nsstring-cocoa.

I think you are also confusing encryption with signatures. The API does not appear to ask you to encrypt you data. It asks you to sign your data. The `enryptedData` variable you have is the signature and does not need to be encrypted. Just do base64 encode on it and assign it to the `Sign` header.